# Когда следует использовать inline для функции/метода?

Tags: c++, inline

Перевод вопроса: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1759300/5697743.

Когда мне следует использовать ключевое слово `inline` для функции или метода в C++?

После просмотра различных объяснений возникли вопросы:

- Когда мне **не следует** использовать ключевое слово `inline` для функции или метода в C++?
- Когда комилятор не знает, что нужно сделать функцию 'встроенной'?
- Отразится ли как-либо использование **многопоточности** в приложении на работе `inline`?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1759300/5697743

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`inline` ближе к `static` или `extern`, чем к указанию компилятору встроить ваши функции.  `extern`, `static` и `inline` используются в основном линковщиком, а не компилятором.

Иногда пишут, что `inline` указывает компилятору, что по-вашему функция должна быть встроенной.  Это было правдой и имело смысл в 1998 году, но спустя двадцать лет компилятору больше не нужны такие подсказки.  Не стоит и говорить, что люди часто ошибаются, когда дело доходит до оптимизации кода, так что большинство компиляторов прямо игнорируют такие "подсказки".

- **`static`** - имя функции/переменной не может быть использовано в других единицах трансляции.  Линковщик должен убедиться, что это случайно не сделано.
- **`extern`** - использовать это имя в данной единице трансляции, но не жаловаться, если оно не определено.  Линковщик разберётся и убедится, что у каждого символа есть адрес.
- **`inline`** - эта функция будет определена в разных единицах трансляции, игнорировать это.  Линковщик должен убедится, что все единицы трансляции используют один и тот же экземпляр.

**Примечание:** В целом, определение шаблонов с `inline` бессмысленно, потому что они уже используют семантику линковки, аналогичную предоставляемой `inline`. Однако, для явной (`explicit`) специализации и инициализации  шаблонов [требуется использовать `inline`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10536588/183120).

---

Ответы на ваши вопросы:

- > Когда мне следует использовать ключевое слово inline для функции или метода в C++?

  Только когда вы хотите определить функцию в заголовке.  Точнее, когда более одного определения функции встречается в различных единицах трансляции. Будет хорошей идеей поместить маленькие (однострочные) функции в заголовок, так как это даст больше информации для оптимизации компилятору. Однако, это увеличит время сборки.
- > Когда мне **не следует** использовать ключевое слово `inline` для функции или метода в C++?

  Не используйте `inline` только из-за уверенности, что ваш код заработает быстрее.
- > Когда компилятор не знает, что нужно сделать функцию 'встроенной'?

  В целом, компилятор умеет выполнять такую оптимизацию лучше вас.  Однако, он не сможет это сделать, если нет определения функции (в данной единице трансляции).  Как правило, в максимально оптимизированном коде все `private` методы встраиваются, просили вы того, или нет.
  Для предотвращения встраивания в GCC используйте `__attribute__(( noinline ))`, а в Visual Studio - `__declspec(noinline)`.
- > Отразится ли как-либо использование **многопоточности** в приложении на работе `inline`?

  Многопоточность не влияет как на работу `inline`, так и на встраивание функций.

Comment: очень хороший ответ

Comment: линковщик не убеждается, что все ссылаются на одну и ту же inline-функцию, он лишь считает, что такие функции одинаковы и может удалить лишние реализации. Есть требование, что все не вс роенный вызовы должны ссылаться на одну и ту же функцию (по одному адресу). Если в разные единицах трансляции попадуться inline-функции с внешней линковкой и одинаковым прототипом, но с разной реализацией, это приведет к нарушению ODR и проблемам.

Answer (score -1):

Внутри определения класса все методы с кодом будут *inline* и определить плохо это или хорошо будет сложно, так как компилятор верит только вам, и предупреждений не будет.

```
class A{
void method(){
 очень большой
 }
};
```

Если код метода выложить вне определения класса с директивой *inline* в header-файле, то есть шанс, что компилятор сделает предупреждение, что код будет больше.

```
class A{
void method();
};
inline void A::method(){...}
```

Всё-бы хорошо, но компиляторы имеют право на всё, и угадать, как они реализуют сложно. Останется только ваше желание видеть предупреждения или нет.